# Listing virtual disks in Java

Tags: java, diskpart

Is there a way to list all virtual disks attached using Java?
I've tried using ProccessBuilder to open diskpart and running command  and then using InputStreamReader, save lines into an array to later extract vhd name. But after running diskpart command my program freezes.

```
try {
    commands.add("cmd.exe");
    commands.add("start");
    commands.add("diskpart");
    commands.add("list vdisk");

    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
    Process p = builder.start();

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: `diskpart` does not take `list vdisk` as an argument, so why did you think that would work? Did you try running `diskpart list vdisk` in a command prompt? Next time, make sure the command you're trying to run actually works, before trying to do it from Java.

Comment: Although the output is different, perhaps using `powershell.exe -Command "Get-VirtualDisk"` would be better, since it does support running with an argument.